# Create options for a select box using php

Tags: php, html

I want to create a very simple `<select>` box containing just numbers, 1,2,3,etc.. So very simply I want

```
<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
</select>
```

However, I would like to use PHP to generate the options instead of creating them all by hand.

How may I go about doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this:

```
<select>

<?php

    define('MAX_OPTIONS', 6);

    for($optionIndex=1; $optionIndex <= MAX_OPTIONS; $optionIndex++){
        echo '<option>' . $optionIndex . '</option>';
    }

?>

</select>
```

Please note that the open and close tag for `<select>` is direct output, its not PHP code, thus the PHP tags.

You could also just print it all through PHP:

```
<?php

    define('MAX_OPTIONS', 6);

    echo '<select>';
    for($optionIndex=1; $optionIndex <= MAX_OPTIONS; $optionIndex++){
        echo '<option>' . $optionIndex . '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';

?>
```

**Hint**

Finally, just to make a small step towards more structured programming, you could create a function:

```
<?php

    function createSelectBox($optionCount){
        $out = '<select>';
        for($idx=1; $idx <= $optionCount; $idx++){
            $out .= '<option>' . $idx . '</option>';
        }
        $out .= '</select>';
        return $out;
    }

?>
```

And then call it - from within PHP (!!) - like this:

```
<?php

    echo createSelectBox(6);

?>
```

Since your generated HTML code will look nice and be functional, it won't serve any practical purpose because no select box can work without the `<option>` tags being served a `value` attribute (which should contain the value that represents the option).

[If needed, read this to gain a better understanding of how `select` works](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/select)

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly. Now I would like to store the selected value (once one is selected) into a variable `$number`. How do I go about this?

Comment: This would require you to post back the data from a `form` (which should include the `select` to a PHP script on your server, which then does the rest. This however would require you to first add a `value` attribute to every `option` and to give the `select` a `name` attribute (and, as mentioned before, the usage of a `form` that contains the `select`). There are ways to do this without a form (by using javascript to set off the request as AJAX, but this is too advanced and would probably make no sense in your coding environment.

Comment: Anyway, if you have another question, please ask it in a separate thread, since (as i assume) your current question has already been answered.

Comment: Check marked your answer, and created the new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20578271/storing-the-value-of-a-select-into-a-variable

Comment: I really don't think defining a global variable is warranted in this context. You don't even use it more than once.

Comment: Thank You @randak - of course that is correct but there is no need to run down all the walls of non-optimized coding in a basic situation such as the one the OP is describing. I used the `constant` because in my example it allowed for better understanding of the `for()` loop and its functionality, along with the additional opportunity to learn a very simple but effective basic tool in PHP: how to define and use `constants`.

Comment: I suppose, but it doesn't really do much good to teach a new technique without also teaching WHEN to use it. I am also not convinced it added any clarity to the `for` loop. However, it could make sense in a larger context.

Comment: You are entitled to your opinion.

Comment: @SquareCat I am not getting much love in my other question (the one I linked above). Do you have a minute to help with that one, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++){
    echo "<option>" . $i . "</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

function options($num) {
    $options = '';

    for ($i = 1; $i < $num + 1; $i++)
    {
        $options .= "\t<option>" . $i . "</option>\n";
    }

    return $options;
}
?>

<select>
    <?php echo options(6); ?>
</select>
```

This function outputs the requested code.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the selectbox using sprintf to make easier to organize the data.

```
<?php

    function createSelectBox($arr){

        $options= '<select>';
        for($i=0; $i <= count($arr); $i++){
            $options .= sprintf("<option value='%s'>%s</option>", $arr[$i]['ID'], $arr[$i]['title']);
        }
        $options .= '</select>';
        return $options;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I came a across this looking for a code fragment.  I ended up writing a function its call and everything that goes with it (albeit here I've put the CSS inside style tags instead of a CSS file)

You can put this in and it'll work.

```
            <?php
            function createOptionBox($boxName,$boxClass ,$productArray){

                $boxHtml = '<select name="'.$boxName.'" class="'.$boxClass.'">';

                for($x=0;$x<count($productArray);$x+=2){

                    $boxHtml .= '<option value="'.$productArray[$x].'">'.$productArray[$x+1].'</option>';

                }

                $boxHtml .= '</select>';

                return($boxHtml);
            }

            $productArray = array("1","ipad","2","phone");
            $boxName = "products";
            $boxClass = "productSelect";

            $productDropDown = createOptionBox($boxName,$boxClass ,$productArray);
            ?>
            <style>

                .productSelect{
                    font-size:12pt;
                    padding: 5px;
                }

            </style>

            <p><?php echo $productDropDown;?></p>
```

the productArray can easily be set up from a database - like mysql, by simply using array_push.

Hope this helps someone.