# Storing the value of a select into a variable

Tags: php, html

With a little help, I have created a PHP generated `<select>` element.

```
<select>
    <?php
        for($optionIndex=1; $optionIndex <= 12; $optionIndex++){
        echo '<option>' . $optionIndex . '</option>';
    } ?>
</select>
```

Now, once a user selects one of the options (1-12), I would like to store that value into a php variable `$number`. How might I go about this?

Comment: As PHP is a *server* language, anything done on the client end will not be executed in the server, so what you have to do is somehow send the select option action to the server. Look into AJAX.

Comment: PHP is server side code. You'd have to send that data back to the server.

Comment: How about adding the select into a form?

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a form which sends data either with GET or POST to your php script.

On the page:

```
<form method="POST" action="path/to/your/script">

    <select name="select_name">
        <option value="1">1</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

PHP script

```
<?php
    $number = $_POST['select_name'];
```

**UPDATE:** You can do this on one page:

```
<?php

if(empty($_POST['select_name'])) {
    // HERE COMES YOUR FORM
} else {
    $number = $_POST['select_name'];
}
```

Comment: The only thing I am unclear on is the `action="path/to/your/script"` What script would this be?

Comment: It is the PHP script that you want to handle your POST. What do you want to do with your number and WHERE? The script can be the same PHP file, but make sure you  check whether you have a POST or not.

Comment: You can leave `action` empty: `<form action method="post">`, which means the browser will use the current URL. Perfectly valid.

Comment: So with this: http://pastebin.com/vY8qJWCi I am getting an error of "Undefined variable: number"

Comment: I got rid of the error by encompassing the `$number` echo in `if(!empty($_POST['no_of_givers'])) {`. However, when I change the value of the select, nothing happens.

Comment: Of course you get an error. You are trying to echo your variable before it gets a value. Move the echo into the else part.

Comment: That makes more sense than what I had, however the issue remains the same. When I select a number, nothing happens

Comment: PHP is a server side language @JCOC611 pointed. You have to hit submit each time you want to update the value or use AJAX.